# Is it okay to use somebody else’s methodology in my own paper (with proper citations) or is this plagiarism?

Tags: plagiarism, methodology

My research is a content analysis about portrayal of mental illness in films. The research I wanted to base my methodology is also about mental-illness representation. My research questions differ to the other researcher’s questions. We also have different sets of films to analyze.

I really want to know if it is okay if I use the same methodology? Or is it considered plagiarism?

Comment: From the question is more about judging the novelty or importance.  And this is really field or topic dependent. For the ok part see answers. Normally first proposers should be even "happy".

Comment: Do you want to apply the same methodology as other researchers, or do you want to copy an existing methodology section from another publication to yours?

Answer (score 13):

Yes, it's okay to reuse other people's methodology to address an original research question.  It is not okay to copy the methods section of their publication.  You must write your own, in addition to citing them.

Comment: One could even say that the methodology described in a paper is part of the scientific contribution, and then others using the same or a derived methodology is how science is supposed to work.

Comment: It's not so uncomon in my field to see a methodology section that is quite short. Along the lines of; "We did the first step with the Kitten method as in paper [A], the second step followed the Tiger technique of paper [B]. We then groomed the cats and counted their whiskers.". The bulk of the methodology becomes citations, often self citations, but not always. Some processes are so common that there is no sense in writing them out fresh for each paper. Would that be acceptable here?

Answer (score -8):

No it's not...you'd better make your own methodology of your research to help yourself how to deal with your data analysis. Maybe you can use them only as reference becsuse copying and using the research methodology of others are unethical, plagiarism and that is a scientific misconduct..

Comment: Sorry, but no. In some fields the methodology is pretty standard. One could even say "common knowledge". And, citing is an absolute guard against plagiarism. One has to consider copyright, of course, in addition to plagiarism. But they are not the same.  If you think they _are_ the same, then you should explore the two ideas more deeply.

Comment: This is also not necessarily a science question.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him-, it could be, actually. We don't know the details. But, for example, misinformation in film can have real world consequences.

Comment: @Buffy Fair enough, edited